# Get the ConnectionString for Alias NameSpace using ARM

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am using the ARM template to deploy some EventHubs with GeoRecovery. I am trying to get the Alias ConnectionString as part of the Output.

I am planning on using the [ListKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/disasterrecoveryconfigs/listauthorizationrules) functions. However I do not know how to make it use on the ARM template. I have searched and tried all possible ways cannot get around it. I am using this,

```
listKeys(resourceId(parameters('ResourceGroupName'), _
         concat('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/disasterRecoveryConfigs/authorizationRules'), _
         parameters('AliasNamespaceName'), 'RootManageSharedAccessKey'),'2015-08-01').primaryConnectionString
```

But I get an error ->

```
: Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'myresource' at line '90' and column '5' is not valid: Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': the type 'Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/disasterRecoveryConfigs/authorizationRules' requires '3' resource name argument(s). Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#resourceid for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'.
```

Can someone help me to get the ListKey in ARM template?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like incorrect segment length - invalid template [incorrect segment length - invalid template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-invalid-template-errors#solution-2---incorrect-segment-lengths) issue. To resolve this you would need to have 3 resource name argument(s) for the type you are using i.e., for "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/disasterRecoveryConfigs/authorizationRules". For more explanation, please refer the example provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-invalid-template-errors#solution-2---incorrect-segment-lengths).

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

this is what you have to do:

```
listKeys(resourceId(parameters('ResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/disasterRecoveryConfigs/authorizationRules', %namespacename%, %disasterrecoveryconfigname%, 'RootManageSharedAccessKey'), '2015-08-01').primaryConnectionString
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code helped me.

`"[listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Eventhub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules', parameters('eventHubNamespaceNamePrimary'), parameters('EventHubName'), 'EventWriter'), '2017-04-01').aliasPrimaryConnectionString]"`

Refereed from  [**servicebus namespaces**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/namespaces/listkeys#accesskeys)